# Why does Boeing use two different door-types (B757 hinge vs. B767 slide)?

Tags: boeing, doors

Why did Boeing use a sliding door for the B767?
[image]
And why wasn't it used in later Boeing planes?

*Edit:*
Looking up other airframe manufacturers I realised that the B767 was introduced prior to the B757. And that other airplanes featured slide-up doors as well but the B767 was the last one featuring them. Could it mean it was some kind of ***fashion*** of the airplane design until the late 70s?

Comment: The 767 photo is a mock up. Is there a photo of real one in real plane?

Comment: @vasin1987 sure https://www.sanspotter.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/delta_air_lines_767-400_ATL-SAN_trip_report_01.jpg but I did not find one where the door is in the process of opening.

Comment: I wouldn't call it fashion. I think what happened was the Concorde/Airbus translating door patents expired between the 767 and the next clean-sheet design, the 777. Now you see the Airbus-style doors on all new jets: 787, SU95, CSeries and E-Jets.

Comment: Why don‘t you compile an answer with that knowledge? In any case thanks for this info!

Comment: @user71659 - Boeing have a 1972/1974 patent for [An aircraft door of the plug type is mounted on three tracks affixed to an airframe for inward and upward movement to open the door.](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3802125).

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick McDonnell Douglas was [first](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3585757A). Here's the patent for the [Airbus style](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3647169A), 1969, beating both of them.

Comment: Between the 757 and 767. The 767 is a wide body and has much more crown space than the 757. The 757 did not have the space for the slide up doors. The 757 door is similar but bigger and more complex than the 737 door. Because it is bigger and heavier, the 757 door also has to have powered emergency assist actuators to help open the doors in an emergency.

Answer (score 5):

Outward swinging doors require a great deal of effort to open and close, and can require the operator to potentially lean outside of the aircraft and risk a fall to close.  The 757 door originally had an issue where shorter operators could not get enough leverage to open (see: [Making It Fly in the Seattle Times](http://old.seattletimes.com/news/business/757/part03/).  Upward doors were used for a while but they are finicky to operate and maintain and if the opening mechanism fails can be very difficult to open in an emergency.

The translating "gooseneck" door was originally designed by Airbus.  The design is simple, reliable and easy to operate.  It has more or less become standard on all new aircraft designs.

Comment: I work on the 757, 767 and the Airbus and I can honestly tell you that I despise the 757 door.

Comment: I also worked on B757 and heard of flight attendants getting sick days from spraining their back. The outward swinging door required opening before some jetways where in position (or re positioning if they missed and a chance of falling) while the sliding door can always be opened after the jetway is against the aircraft. It is also easier and safer to seal a door for flight that closes with cabin pressure, than against it - less chance of explosive decompression.

Comment: Pretty much all passenger doors are "plug" style.  Even ones that eventually swing outside the aircraft usually open inward first to move the seals and latches clear and therefore cannot be opened with a pressure differential.  This is another problem with the early hinged doors, a strong operator can actually unlatch the door against a modest pressure differential.  This has happened on the ground several times where the interior of the aircraft remains pressurized due to a malfunctioning pressurization system.  The door opens violently and has caused at least two fatal incidents.